# Push nested tag value into PHP array

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

How can you push the `sample_id` value into the array using PHP DOM, along with `first` and `samples`?

I've tried adding another foreach loop, but I'm getting various notices such as

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<maintable>
  <group>
    <first>text1</first>
    <second>text2</second>
    <samples a="link" b="link">
      <sample_id>000555</sample_id>
    </samples>
  </group>
  <group>
    <first>text3</first>
    <second>text4</second>
    <samples a="link" b="link">
      <sample_id>111000</sample_id>
    </samples>
  </group>  
</maintable>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents($file);
$content = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $text);

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$xml->loadXML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $xml );


$query = '/maintable/group[first="text3"]';                 
$nodes = $xpath->query( $query );


$var = array();
foreach( $nodes as $k => $node )
{
    foreach( $node->childNodes as $cnode )
    {
        if ($cnode->nodeName == 'first')
        {
                $var[$k]["first"] = (string)$cnode->textContent;
        }

        if ($cnode->nodeName == 'samples')
        {
                $var[$k]["samp_url"] = (string)$cnode->getAttribute("a");

        }

        if ($cnode->nextSibling->nodeName == 'sample_id')
        {
                $var[$k]["sample_id"] = (string)$cnode->nextSibling->textContent;

        }
    }   
}
//print_r($cnode->childNodes);
?>
```

**Attempt to loop thru nodeList**

```
$var = array();

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('/maintable/group[first="text3"]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) 
{
   foreach( $node->childNodes as $cnode )
   {
       if (is_array($cnode))
       {
           foreach( $cnode->childNodes as $cn )
           {
               $var[]["sample_id"] = (string)$cn->textContent;
           }
       }
   }   
}

var_dump($var);
```

Comment: first off, your query looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMXpath::query()` can only return node lists, `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalars, too. The second argument of `query()/evaluate()` is the context node. If provided, the Xpath expression will be relative to it.

So you can select the node(s) first, iterate the list and use `evaluate()` again to fetch the values:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$results = [];

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('/maintable/group[first="text3"]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $results[] = [
    'first' => $xpath->evaluate('string(first)', $node),
    'sample_url' => $xpath->evaluate('string(samples/@a)', $node),
    'sample_id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(samples/sample_id)', $node)
  ];
}

var_dump($results);
```

Output: https://eval.in/171656

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(5) "text3"
    ["sample_url"]=>
    string(4) "link"
    ["sample_id"]=>
    string(6) "111000"
  }
}
```

Fetching only the sample id from the document works, too:

```
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/maintable/group[first="text3"]/samples/sample_id)')
);
```

Output:

```
string(6) "111000"
```

Comment: Is it possible to loop through the child tag `sample_id` also?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the string() typecast. `$xpath->evaluate('samples/sample_id', $node)` will return a node list. You can use foreach to iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath query to select the correct element you're after:

```
/maintable/group/first[text()="text3"]/../samples/sample_id
```

Explanation:

```
/maintable                # from the top of the document, select the maintable element
/group                    # select group element, child of maintable
/first[text()="text3"]    # select 'first' element, child of group with text = 'text3'
/..                       # move up to the parent of the 'first' element
/samples                  # find samples element, child of this parent
/sample_id                # find sample_id element, child of this parent
```

Then you can push your text value (the sample id) by using `$node->nodeValue`. Example:

```
$query = '/maintable/group/first[text()="text3"]/../samples/sample_id';                 
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

$var = array();
foreach($nodes as $k => $node) {
    $var[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

print_r($var);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111000
)
```

[Here's a good read](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_nodes.asp) for learning how to use XPath selectors.

Comment: How would you add additional values `first` `second` `samples` to the query?